# Obtener el porcentaje de una columna en Spark

Tags: pyspark, spark

Estoy intentado obtener el porcentaje sobre el total en pyspark del campo "item_type". Tengo el siguiente código:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df2.select(df2.item_type,f.col('count')/f.sum('count'))\
    .groupBy(df2.item_type)\
    .count()\
    .show()
```

Al ejecutarlo me salta el siguiente error: "pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "cannot resolve '`count`' given input columns: [price, product_id, way, shop_id,..."

Comment: ¿La columna `count` existe en tu dataframe? ¿Podrías colocar una muesta de tus datos?

Answer (score 0):

No está claro lo que estás buscando pero tomemos un ejemplo:

```
df  = spark.createDataFrame(
  [
('1','ABC','A','200'),
('1','DEF','B','350'),
('1','GEH','B','120'),
('1','JIK','C','100'),
('1','LMO','A','40'),
('2','ABC','A','10'),
('2','DEF','A','20'),
('2','GEH','C','30'),
('2','JIK','C','40'),
('2','LMO','A','50')
  ], ['ID','Prod_Name','item_type','count']
)

+---+---------+---------+-----+
| ID|Prod_Name|item_type|count|
+---+---------+---------+-----+
|  1|      ABC|        A|  200|
|  1|      DEF|        B|  350|
|  1|      GEH|        B|  120|
|  1|      JIK|        C|  100|
|  1|      LMO|        A|   40|
|  2|      ABC|        A|   10|
|  2|      DEF|        A|   20|
|  2|      GEH|        C|   30|
|  2|      JIK|        C|   40|
|  2|      LMO|        A|   50|
+---+---------+---------+-----+
```

Suponga que queiras calcular el porcentage por `item_type` y por `ID`. Entonces aggregamos y calculamos la soma por `ID` y `item_type` y finalmente usamos uma Window function para calcular la soma por `ID`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

(df
    .groupBy('ID', 'item_type')
    .agg(F.sum('count').alias('qty'))
    .withColumn('pct', F.col('qty') / F.sum('qty').over(W.partitionBy('ID')))
    .show()
)
```

Output:

```
+---+---------+-----+-------------------+
| ID|item_type|  qty|                pct|
+---+---------+-----+-------------------+
|  1|        A|240.0| 0.2962962962962963|
|  1|        B|470.0| 0.5802469135802469|
|  1|        C|100.0|0.12345679012345678|
|  2|        A| 80.0| 0.5333333333333333|
|  2|        C| 70.0| 0.4666666666666667|
+---+---------+-----+-------------------+
```